# displayjson instead of hal json file

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest

I have a small application using Spring boot spring data and angularJs where I can read data from my table  and display it on my page.
the problem I m new I don' know how to display a Hal Json format , I know how to display **simple Json** format but **not Hal json**. I want to get json file as a response like below , thanks for any help . Because I want to display both  **"id"** and **"nom"** from the table not only **"nom"**.

my Rest :

```
package com.Benamar.dao;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import com.Benamar.entities.Categorie;
public class CategorieRest {
@Autowired
private CategorieRepository categorieRepository;
@RequestMapping(value="/categories",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Categorie> afficher()
 {
    return categorieRepository.findAll();
 }
}
```

RestResource:

```
package com.Benamar.dao;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

import com.Benamar.entities.Categorie;
import com.Benamar.entities.Produit;

@RepositoryRestResource
public interface CategorieRepository extends JpaRepository<Categorie, Long>          
     {     
 }
```

index.html :

```
 <body ng-app="MyApp">
  <div id="categorie"  ng-controller="CategController"  >

<button ng-click="chargerCategories()" >Charger Cat</button>

  <h1>  Categorie</h1>
  <div   >
   <table id="table-2">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Id</th>
              <th>Nom</th>

          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="c in categories._embedded.categories">

              <td>{{c.id}}</td>
              <td>{{c.nom}}</td>

          </tr>
      </tbody>

  </table>
```

Angular js :

```
  var app=angular.module("MyApp",[]);
  app.controller("CategController",function($scope, $http){
  $scope.categories=null;
  $scope.chargerCategories=function(){
  // get the values of table categories as json format (Rest findAll)
  $http.get("http://localhost:8989/categories")
  .then (function (success)
    {
     $scope.categories=success.data;
    },
    function(error){console.log="erreur !!!!"}
    );
  }

});
```

when I get the categories from database I got it like this :

```
{
"_embedded": {
  "categories": [
    {
     "nom": "ordinateurs",
     "_links": {
        "self": {
           "href": "http://localhost:8989/categories/1"
                },
         "categorie": {
           "href": "http://localhost:8989/categories/1"
                      }
               }
    },
  {
   "nom": "tablets",
   "_links": {
      "self": {
       "href": "http://localhost:8989/categories/2"
               },
       "categorie": {
          "href": "http://localhost:8989/categories/2"
                   }
              }
         },
{
"nom": "telephones",
"_links": {
"self": {
"href": "http://localhost:8989/categories/3"
},
"categorie": {
"href": "http://localhost:8989/categories/3"
}
}
},
{
"nom": "calculatrices",
"_links": {
"self": {
"href": "http://localhost:8989/categories/4"
},
"categorie": {
"href": "http://localhost:8989/categories/4"
}
}
},
{
"nom": "tbi",
"_links": {
"self": {
"href": "http://localhost:8989/categories/5"
},
"categorie": {
"href": "http://localhost:8989/categories/5"
}
}
},
{
"nom": "readers",
"_links": {
"self": {
"href": "http://localhost:8989/categories/6"
},
"categorie": {
"href": "http://localhost:8989/categories/6"
}
}
},
{
"nom": "tv",
"_links": {
"self": {
"href": "http://localhost:8989/categories/7"
},
"categorie": {
"href": "http://localhost:8989/categories/7"
}
}
}
]
},
"_links": {
"self": {
"href": "http://localhost:8989/categories"
},
"profile": {
"href": "http://localhost:8989/profile/categories"
}
},
"page": {
"size": 20,
"totalElements": 7,
"totalPages": 1,
"number": 0
}
}
```

but I want json file like this :

```
    {
"content": [
{
"id": 1,
"nom": "ordinateurs",

},
{
"id": 2,
"nom": "tablets",
},
{
"id": 3,
"nom": "telephones",
},
{
"id": 4,
"nom": "cellulaires",
},
{
"id": 5,
"nom": "tbi",
 },
{
"id": 6,
"nom": "readers",
 },
 {
"id": 7,
"nom": "tv",
 }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually I forgot to put annotation @RestController in my class Rest so it becomes like this :

```
package com.Benamar.dao;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import com.Benamar.entities.Categorie;

@RestController
public class CategorieRest {
@Autowired
private CategorieRepository categorieRepository;
@RequestMapping(value="/categories",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Categorie> afficher()
 {
    return categorieRepository.findAll();
 }
}
```